# input from shell in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script

i have a bash script i would like modify to support input from shell
atm i have to type the link after i have run the script

```
wiak@test:~$ scripts/lget.sh
gimme cookie!
https://raw.github.com/nwgat/scripts/master/lget.sh
80 bytes transferred
done.
wiak@test:~$
```

like this input from shell

`lget https://github.com/nwgat/scripts/raw/master/lftp.sh`

the bash script

```
echo "gimme cookie!"
read down
lftp -e 'pget -n 5 '$down' && exit'
echo "done."
```

its also here on github if someone wants to fork it
https://github.com/nwgat/scripts/blob/master/lget.sh

software needed to make it work: 
lftp http://lftp.yar.ru/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "gimme cookie!"
#read down
lftp -e 'pget -n 5 '$1' && exit'
echo "done."
```

Now you can pass the link as a command line option. $1 expands to the first command line option you pass to your shell script.

Comment: so that is how that worked, thx for the help

Comment: Yes :) You're most welcome. I am glad to have been of help.